# Moving Background Using HTML or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, background

I'm trying to create a similar effect as the background shown in the website below. Would prefer HTML if possible, if not JavaScript should be fine. Thanks!

[Example](http://www.elderscrolls.com/skyrim/)

Comment: it appears that this page uses some js to change the `background-position` property of `body` during scroll.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you have problems with? This is not a site to just come and ask for code.

Comment: I tried various HTML/CSS properties, but none worked how I hoped. I'm still not to grips with JavaScript so wasn't even sure where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT #2**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkyt7/3/

---

**EDIT**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DsRcN/2/

---

Have the content of your website inside a container DIV or something with `overflow: auto`. And give a background-image for your body element. In the container's onscroll, reposition the body's background image as needed.

CSS:

```
body {
  background-image: url(bg.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.container { /* your site's content should be inside this container */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.container').scroll(function() {
  $('body').css('background-position', ($(this).scrollTop() * 0.9)+'px');
});
```

You can fine tune the 0.9 depending on how much depth effect you want.

Comment: Thank you. This should work perfectly. I'll try this when I'm on my server.

Comment: Please check the fiddle in my updated answer.

Comment: Does the entire site have to be inside a separate div?

Comment: Well.. Having it in a separate DIV allows us to tweak the body's background properties more easily than otherwise. If you play around the styles in the fiddle there, you may just be able to get the effect going without a separate div too. Let me see if something like that can be done.

Comment: Added a better fiddle. No content div etc. Directly operating on the body element. :)

Comment: Updated the post with the correct URL for the new fiddle. The previous one was not the latest one!